# SQL Error. Get the last particular fee charged on every type of account

Tags: sql

I have different types of accounts in my dataset, so for each Acct I want to get the last TransProcessDate with a particular code and Narrative. (Basically show the date when the last particular fee was charged)

I have here given an example for S8 type account, but this code is throwing an error:

> "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
> subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
> an expression."

What am I doing wrong? Please help. Thanks

```
CASE 
    WHEN acct = 'S8' 
        THEN (SELECT DISTINCT transprocessdate 
              FROM qpcureporting.dbo.acctran t1 
              INNER JOIN 
                  (SELECT MAX(transprocessdate) maxdate, id, transcode 
                   FROM qpcureporting.dbo.acctran AT 
                   GROUP BY id, transcode) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
                                              AND t1.transprocessdate = t2.maxdate 
                                              AND t1.transcode = ('67') 
                                              AND transnarrative = 'WITHDRAWAL FEES') 
    WHEN acct = 'S6'   
         ....
 ....
```

Comment: Try `select MAX(TransProcessDate) from t1.TransCode = ('67') and TransNarrative = 'WITHDRAWAL FEES` as the subquery.

Comment: please use Top 1 to get a single record.

Comment: @SainPradeep: `TOP 1` without an accompanying `ORDER BY` is dangerous and careless....

Comment: Please include which DB server (including version) is being used. There are different tags for different servers.

Comment: Since SQL includes data definition, a [mcve] for an [SQL question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/90527) should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for sample tables and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data. Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Comment: Duplicate of "[Attempting to use a subquery as an expression, need alternatives / help](//stackoverflow.com/q/6584350/90527)", "[SQL queries in Case statement](//stackoverflow.com/q/6122232/90527)", "[Attempting to use a subquery as an expression, need alternatives / help](//stackoverflow.com/q/6584350/90527)", or one of the many other questions about this error in the context of `CASE` expressions. Please [search](//stackoverflow.com/help/searching) before asking to make sure you're not asking a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates).

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT t1.Id,t1.TransProcessDate 
        FROM qpcureporting.dbo.acctran t1 
      INNER JOIN 
       (SELECT max(TransProcessDate) maxdate, id,transcode 
        FROM qpcureporting.dbo.acctran  AT 
         where transcode = ( '67' )
        AND transnarrative = 'WITHDRAWAL FEES'
        GROUP BY id, transcode
       )  t2 ON t1.id= t2.id 
            AND t1.TransProcessDate = t2.maxdate                                                     works fine on it's own but when it placed in the then part of case it throws the error.